# Correct pattern to acquire a WakeLock in a BroadcastReceiver and release it in a Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, wakelock

Even after a lot of research I am still not completely sure if the way how I implement a `WakeLock` for a `Service` started by a `BroadcastReceiver` is correct - even though it seems to work fine. The broadcast receiver gets intents sent to it from an alarm, so to start with, from the API docs of `AlarmManager`:

> If your alarm receiver called Context.startService(), it is possible
>   that the phone will sleep before the requested service is launched. To
>   prevent this, your BroadcastReceiver and Service will need to
>   implement a separate wake lock policy to ensure that the phone
>   continues running until the service becomes available.

So, in `onReceive()` I do:

```
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SomeService.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);

    if(SomeService.wakeLock == null) {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        SomeService.wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
                SomeService.WAKE_LOCK_TAG);
    }
    if(! SomeService.wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        SomeService.wakeLock.acquire();
    }
```

and in the service I do:

```
    try {
        // Do some work
    } finally {
        if(wakeLock != null) {
            if(wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                wakeLock.release();
            }
            wakeLock = null;
        }
    }
```

The `SomeService.wakeLock`field is package private, static and volatile.

What I am unsure about is the check using `isHeld()` - does it really tell me if a `WakeLock` is acquired or not, and do I need to do this check at all?

Comment: This question deserves regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I am unsure about is the check using `isHeld()` - does it really tell me if a `WakeLock` is acquired or not, and do I need to do this check at all?

Actually slightly tricky to answer. Looking at the source for `PowerManager` and `PowerManager.WakeLock` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/PowerManager.java) the `WakeLock.acquire()` and `WakeLock.acquireLocked()` methods are as follows...

```
public void acquire(long timeout) {
    synchronized (mToken) {
        acquireLocked();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mReleaser, timeout);
    }
}

private void acquireLocked() {
    if (!mRefCounted || mCount++ == 0) {
        // Do this even if the wake lock is already thought to be held (mHeld == true)
        // because non-reference counted wake locks are not always properly released.
        // For example, the keyguard's wake lock might be forcibly released by the
        // power manager without the keyguard knowing.  A subsequent call to acquire
        // should immediately acquire the wake lock once again despite never having
        // been explicitly released by the keyguard.
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mReleaser);
        try {
            mService.acquireWakeLock(mToken, mFlags, mTag, mWorkSource);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
        mHeld = true;
    }
}
```

...`mService` is an `IPowerManager` interface and the source for it isn't available so it's hard to tell what may or may not go wrong when attempting to call `acquireWakeLock(...)`.

In any case, the only exception that can be caught is `RemoteException` and the `catch` block does nothing. Immediately after the try/catch, `mHeld` is set `true` regardless.

In short, if you call `isHeld()` immediately after `acquire()` the result will always be `true`.

Looking further into the source for `PowerManager.WakeLock` shows similar behaviour for `release()` which calls `release(int flags)` where the `mHeld` member is always set to `false` regardless of what happens.

In conclusion I'd suggest it is always a good idea to check `isHeld()` just as a best practice in case later versions of Android change this behaviour of the `WakeLock` methods.

Comment: I should also just have a look at the Android sources when the documentation isn't sufficient (which is quite rare, I think) - thanks!

Comment: You suggest calling `isHeld()` before calling `release()` in case future versions of Android change the behaviour. Don't you think that if a future version changed its behaviour, it would (for backwards-compatibility reasons and to prevent a lot of market apps from crashing) need to deal properly with calls to `release()` where the lock is not actually held? Not only that, but the example code which is in the source code for `PowerManager` and in the documentation explicitly calls `acquire()` and `release()` unconditionally. Also, since `WakeLock`s are reference counted, it is required that...

Comment: ...you call `release()` the same number of times you call `acquire()`.  Of course, by all means call `isHeld()` before calling `release()` but I wouldn't brand this a "best practice".

Answer (score 4):

Manage you wakeLock inside a singleton (unique instance accessible through all your context and object)

Use a singleton instance of a custom class, then you may get wakelock object reference from call to call ,

here an singleton example

```
class MyData {
   private static MyData mMydata= null; // unique reference ( singleton objet container)

   private PowerManager.Wakelock myobject = null; // inside the unique object container we have the unique working object to be use  by the application
   // can't make instance from outside... we want to have single instance
   // we want that outside use method "getInstance" to be able to use the object
   private MyData() {
   }

   // retrieve and/or create new unique instance
   public static MyData getInstance() {
     if (mMydata ==  null) mMyData = new MyData();
     return   mMyData;
   }

   // Works with your memory stored object
   // get...
   public PowerManager.WakeLock getMyWakelock() {
   return myobject;
   }
   // set ...
   public void setMyWakeLock(PowerManager.WakeLock obj) {
    myobject = obj;
   }
}
```

in your application to handle your "wakelock" object your may access it like

```
// set a created wakelock
MyData.getInstance().setMyWakeLock(wl);
// get the saved wakelock object
PowerManager.WakeLock obj =  MyData.getInstance().getMyWakeLock();
```

Comment: Right, static singletons seem to be quite common in Android. I am not sure about the advantages and disadvantages compared to use a static member, also thinking about unit testing.

Comment: it's mainly because it is a largely accepted designed pattern commonly used in most OO languages... But if classic static is right for you, you're free to use it :)

Comment: I don't really agree - I think a static singleton is a bit of an antipattern, especially in JEE (what I mainly work with), and I'd use it only if there is no other way. But that holds true for any static stuff so I try to avoid it as much as I can.
And, BTW, the preferred pattern for a singleton is the enum one (see Joshua Blochs "Effective Java").

Comment: @Torsten : You're right, that why most of implementation of this pattern use not simple static but "Thread" singleton or "Context Class Loader" singleton etc...

Answer (score 3):

All this job can be done by a helper and native class called [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Deprecated since API level 26.0.0

Comment: @EmmanuelDevaux: It works in all API levels where the question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think android.os.Messenger may be a better way

for the receiver:

```
public class MessengerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private static final String TAG = "MessengerReceiver";

    private final MessengerHandler mHandler = new MessengerHandler();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        mHandler.mWakeLock = ((PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Service.POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "myreceiver");
        mHandler.mWakeLock.acquire();
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive:: mHandler.mWakeLock=" + mHandler.mWakeLock + ", intent=" + intent + ", this=" + this);
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MessengerService.class).putExtra("messenger", new Messenger(mHandler)));
    }

    static class MessengerHandler extends Handler {

        WakeLock mWakeLock;
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mWakeLock != null){
                mWakeLock.release();
                Log.e(TAG, "handleMessage:mWakeLock=" + mWakeLock);
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }

    }
}
```

for the service:

```
public class MessengerService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MessengerService";
    public MessengerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand:: intent=" + intent);
        final Messenger messenger = intent.getParcelableExtra("messenger");
        try {
            messenger.send(Message.obtain());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

### This method work properly even if service & receiver run in different process.