# Call Service With AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I have created one service which I want to call periodically through AlarmManager. I have written code for same, But it's not calling. If I call BroadcasrReciever through AlarmManager, then it's working fine.

Below is my Code,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdateService1.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 20000, 11000, pendingIntent);

    }
```

My service class is,

```
public class LocationUpdateService1 extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return  null;
    }
}
```

My manifiest file,

```
<service
            android:name=".Services.LocationUpdateService1">
        </service>
```

Do I have to create BroadcastReceiver class to call my service ?
What is wrong in my code ? and why it's not calling periodically ?

Comment: You need to get your `PendingIntent` with `PendingIntent.getService()` - not `getBroadcast()` - if you want it to start a `Service`. Also, `onBind()` isn't going to fire unless something binds the `Service`. You probably want `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use PendingIntent.getService() or getBroadcast with AlarmManager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308298/should-i-use-pendingintent-getservice-or-getbroadcast-with-alarmmanager)

Comment: I changed to getBroadcast() to getService(), Still not working

Comment: Did you check if `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()` are called?

Comment: Please edit your post to show that you are using `getService()` and not `getBroadcast()`.

Comment: I removed service thing, And for now I am using PendingIntent.getBroadcast() only... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you **don't** use *PendingIntent.getBroadcast*, it wouldn't work. Using getService() instead, like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Not able to understand parameters. If possible, Transform my code with correct one.

Comment: @KevalPatel that's simple, just update the answer :)