# android - set Alarm just once - AlarmManager vs WorkManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-workmanager

on button clicked, I want to set an alarm that sounds and shows a custom dialog after one hour. If this dialog is not closed, I need to show the same dialog after 15 minutes.
I have checked **AlarmManager and WorkManager** but I do not know which one to use. I have read AlarmManager is better in this cases when needed to trigger alarms at specific time, but haven't seen anything about scheduling alarms just once (what I am interested in and I do not know how to do it), I have only read about scheduling repeating alarms.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an alarm just once as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#type). This will schedule an alarm for 15 minutes. In case of one hour you can adjust accordingly.

```
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        15 * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Which is the difference betweeen the PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...) and .getService(...) ? (I'll need to use FLAG_NO_CREATE to make it cancellable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308298/should-i-use-pendingintent-getservice-or-getbroadcast-with-alarmmanager
Check this it'll answer your question.