# do I need a wake lock in my broadcastreceiver if I'm not starting a service or an activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wakelock

I have a broadcastreceiver called by an Alarm (scheduled with AlarmManager). In this receiver I'm only querying a register from the database, and launching a notification. I readed that a wake lock is needed when a service or an activity is started from a broadcast receiver, but, do I need a wake lock if I only want to show a notificacion (in the notification panel)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38816085/6456129 may be helpful

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> In this receiver I'm only querying a register from the database, and launching a notification.

Do not do database I/O on the main application thread.

> I readed that a wake lock is needed when a service or an activity is started from a broadcast receiver, but, do I need a wake lock if I only want to show a notificacion (in the notification panel)?

In general, no, you would not need a `WakeLock` from a `BroadcastReceiver`, even one that is invoked via a `_WAKEUP` alarm. `AlarmManager` guarantees in this case that it will keep the device awake using its own `WakeLock`.

However, again, in this case, you really should not be doing database I/O on the main application thread, and `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. The proper pattern here is that you move your "querying a register from the database, and launching a notification" to an `IntentService`, started by your `BroadcastReceiver`, so that the work is done on a background thread. This *will* require a `WakeLock`, as you are now doing work outside of `onReceive()`. I have [a `WakefulIntentService` that manages the `WakeLock` for you](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), if you wish to use it.

Comment: Thanks! You answered all my questions about it :) I'll take a look at your WakefulIntentService to do all the work in an IntentService, and using a WakeLock.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but i think there is a chance that the device goes back to sleep while the BroadCastReceiver's onReceive() has finished, but your WakefulIntentService isn't started yet or hasn't acquired a wakelock yet, therefore i'd suggest to simply use a WakefulBroadcastReceiver (was added to the support library after the accepted answer): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: @Su-AuHwang: "correct me if i'm wrong" -- you are wrong. `WakefulIntentService` is specifically designed for this scenario. "therefore i'd suggest to simply use a WakefulBroadcastReceiver" -- there are pros and cons for each approach; there is nothing intrinsically wrong with either of them.

Comment: @CommonsWare, shouldnt WAKE_LOCK be required in every case when i start a service? Why only in some special cases? The CPU can go to sleep in any case.

Comment: @Diffy: "shouldnt WAKE_LOCK be required in every case when i start a service?" -- only if you need the CPU to stay awake. "The CPU can go to sleep in any case" -- correct. Not every service needs the CPU to stay awake. And since keeping the CPU awake drains the battery, causing users to consider attacking offending developers with torches and pitchforks, we only use a `WakeLock` when **absolutely required**.

Comment: @CommonsWare, how can a task run without using CPU. For example, downloading anything in service, or playing a song in the background? Everything will require CPU.

Comment: @Diffy: "Everything will require CPU" -- of course not. There are any number of situations where a service is needed, but the work does not need to be performed continuously. `InputMethodService`, `AccessibilityService`, `PrintService`, `RemoteViewsService`, `SpellCheckerService`, `TextToSpeechService`, etc. do not need to keep the CPU on all the time. In some cases, the framework will manage the `WakeLock` for you (e.g., `JobService`). If you have further concerns in this are, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @CommonsWare in your implementation here https://goo.gl/6LCZSM , especially the OnAlarmReceiver class , you have extended a plain BroadcastReceiver instead of a Wakeful one. I also see that your WakefulIntentService.java class manually acquires and releases the lock from the PowerManager. lets say instead of this, I make a BroadcastReciever that extends from the Wakeful one without all the PowerManager boilerplate code, would that be equivalent to your implementation? Ever since I saw your implementation answer at a couple of places on stackoverflow :) I was wondering if they are same

Comment: @PirateApp: "you have extended a plain BroadcastReceiver instead of a Wakeful one" -- correct. First, that demo predates `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. Second, you either use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` *or* `WakefulIntentService`, not both. "would that be equivalent to your implementation?" -- `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and `WakefulIntentService` are designed to address the same problem, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the clarification Mr Mark Murphy :) I have read your books, you truly are a colossal programmer

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is necessary.
I remember that in the Kernel level, the CPU will be kept running for about 5 seconds.
So if you cannot finishing send your notification within 5 seconds, you have to grasp a wake lock. And release it after you finished your work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only one question more: do I need to start a service? or can I do the work on the receiver?

Comment: Downvote because BroadcastReceiver cannot do hard work (just a few seconds, so 5 seconds is really fine). If you want to do hard work, start a service.