# Android: Do I need a WakeLock for a really short task?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, wakelock

I have a BroadcastReceiver that is called when a GCM message arrives.
All it does is that it sets an "update on next app start"-flag in the shared preferences, and pushes a notification.
So far, I haven't encountered a problem without a WakeLock, and I would like to keep app permissons as few as possible.
Is it likely, that the device will go back to sleep during this millisecond process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's all your doing, then you [**don't** need a WakeLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520509/do-i-need-a-wake-lock-in-my-broadcastreceiver-if-im-not-starting-a-service-or-a). If you were doing a bigger task that took more time then you should use a service, if it's only a few seconds (less in your case) you can go without it.